# Splitting up an each block, into blocks depending on content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a tricky one to express, I'll give it a shot though:
I have defined `@model = Model.all` which includes both `depart_at` and `arrive_at`. I now need to run through these, in groups of date. (Each is a datetime in the database).
I've tried a few things, but I can't seem to get anything to work here.

```
<% @departure_times.each do |departure_time| %>

<% end %>
```

is the current code. I can't seem to find anything in the Rails API about, what I can do to chunk up by the date of depart_at.

**Edit:**
The expected outcome is something alike:

```
**date** - 10:15, 11:15, 20:30
**date** - 11:15, 12:30, 14:15
```

etc - The meaning for this, is to group the output by the date of the timestamp.

Comment: Please show the desired output.

Comment: Expected output is added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might prepare the chunked array in the controller:

```
@dt_grouped = @departure_times.group_by do |departure_time|
  Date.parse(departure_time.depart_at.to_s).to_s
end
```

This will produce a `Hash` instance like:

```
{ '2016-03-08' => [dt1, dt2, dt3,...], ...}
```

and then in view:

```
<% @dt_grouped.each do |date, times| %>
  <%= date %> — <%= times.join ', ' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Didn't really think of this before! Am I correct, assuming that Date.parse returns the date only?

Comment: Give it a try :) Well, yes, it does.

Comment: It seems, that by following code: `<% @dt_grouped.each do |date, times| %>
      <label><%= date %></label>
      <% times.each do |departure_time| %>.....` it only prints the first date.

Comment: Oh wait - I spotted it. It seems that `Date.parse(departure_time.depart_at.to_s).to_s` works instead - Just added the `.depart_at.to_s` instead - Update your answer, and I'll accept it!